# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError library apache poi netbeans

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to use the apache POI in order to handle some xlsx files.I downloaded the zip and added the JAR files to the libraries.When I used the apache POI classes to my project they were found(the project found no errors) but when I ran the project i got the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. 
   What could be the possible problem?(the JARS are added correctly).Thank you

Comment: can you please paste the stack trace here?

Comment: Have you included jar files in server classpath?. which server are you using?

Comment: in my case I also need to paste the jar files inside server's lib folder. (JBoss)

Comment: Could be that your .jar files are not in the same version

Comment: It could be either jar is not found or multiple jars with different version is in class path. If it is not maven project then add them to lib folder

Comment: Why don't you use Maven?